# How to apply form onSubmit on one submit type only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have an HTML form which on submit calls a validation method. Now, in this form I have two Submit types:

`<input type="submit" name="abc" value="abc"`>

`<input type="submit" name="xyz" value="xyz"`>

Now, when I click on any submit button the validation method will be called. But I want to call the validation method only when the 'abc' button is clicked and not when 'xyz' is clicked.

Is there any way using JavaScript to handle this?

Comment: how about creating a function validation for `button abc` only?

Comment: Just check the `input` `name` in the function, and validate depending on if it matches or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to validate form on only one submit button then do this on form submit

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  var btn = event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.value;
  if (btn === 'abc') {
    alert('true');
  } else {
    alert('false');
  }
});
```

[Demo - Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anegaxrx/)

Comment: Do `<input>` elements support `onsubmit`? I thought only `<form>` did

Comment: @RaunakKathuria I tried the Fiddle, it's not working for me. Nothing happens when I click in both the buttons except the loading of page. Please suggest.

Comment: @rohit it works for me, which browser are you testing?